# Type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.EmbeddedFormField' does not have a public property named 'div'. on import of page

Tags: sharepoint

I exported a site page on a SharePoint 2013 site using designer.  I then tried to import the page on a different SharePoint 2013.

When I try accessing the page on the 2nd site, I get the error:
Type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.EmbeddedFormField' does not have a public property named 'div'.

Page works just fine on the first site.

Any idea what would cause this issue?

The page is restricted to only members of a certain group.  I am not sure if that would cause the issue or not.

Comment: I had same problem. I'm not sure what causes this issue but I managed to solve it by copying entire page source between servers.

Comment: What do you mean by "entire page source"? Do you mean that you created a new page at the target location then literally copied the HTML contents?